# drupal_mail() sends two emails, second email is empty

Tags: 7, emails

I'm using the following code for sending out an email with `drupal_mail()`

```
$module = 'example_module';
$key = 'key';
$language = language_default();
$params = array();
$from = 'email@email.com';
$send = TRUE;
$message = drupal_mail($module, $key, $order->mail, $language, $params, $from, $send);
$message['subject'] = 'Subject';
$message['body'] = $message_body;

// Retrieve the responsible implementation for this message.
$system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);
// Format the message body.
$message = $system->format($message);
// Send e-mail.
$message['result'] = $system->mail($message);
```

I get two emails after the function that contains this runs, one email is perfect, the other email is completely empty.

The function that contains the code above only runs once, I tested by printing out some text with dsm().

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`drupal_mail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) function you call will send an email.

Then when you call `$system->mail($message);` that will send a second email.

Here is an example of how to use `drupal_mail` ([taken from here](https://api.drupal.org/comment/53243#comment-53243)):

```
/**
* Implements hook_entity_insert().
*
*/
function dummy_module_node_insert($node) {
  $module = 'dummy_module';
  $key = 'dummy_key';
  $language = language_default();
  $params = array(
    '@url' => url('node/' . $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE)),
    '@title' => $node->title,
  );

  drupal_mail($module, $key, $mail, $language, $params);
}

/**
* Implements hook_mail().
*/
function dummy_module_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $message['subject'] = t("@title event registration confirmation", $params);
  $message['body'] = array();
  $message['body'][] = t("Hello", $params);
  $message['body'][] = t("Node has been created @title (@url).", $params);
}
```

The user who posted this code originally labeled it as *"The propper way to use this:"* and I've had success using this code before.

Answer (score -1):

```
$module = 'example_module';
$key = 'key';
$language = language_default();
$params = array();
$from = 'email@email.com';
$send = FALSE; //                               <-- HERE
$message = drupal_mail($module, $key, $order->mail, $language, $params, $from, $send);
$message['subject'] = 'Subject';
$message['body'] = $message_body;

// Retrieve the responsible implementation for this message.
$system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);
// Format the message body.
$message = $system->format($message);
// Send e-mail.
$message['result'] = $system->mail($message);
```

Just set $send = FALSE; to disable the blank email your code is correct as well